# Is it more safe to manual install a .deb file then installing from test (apt, Debian'ish)

Tags: debian, apt, deb

I want to keep my debian system as "stable" as possible, but I need the package `virt-top` which only exist in test repository

I see two options:

1. Adding test to the repository-file and install the package with `apt install ---target-release test virt-top`. I'm afraid there is a risk of installing to many dependent packages from test and/or uninstall/overwrite current installed stable packages.
2. Download the .deb file and install it manually with `dpkg -i file.deb`.
   It might complain about dependencies, but I seem to be able to fix that with `apt-get install -fix-broken` (*test is not added to the repository file*).

Is it correct that option 2 is more "safe" to the system overall. There is a change that the package might not work, but there is a less change of breaking the system overall, right?
(I did try this with virt-top and it worked very well).

Any recommendation or correction of my assumption is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would first try a backport repository : but they don’t seem to propose you the `virt-top` package.

`dpkg -i` seems a good option, but I would add dependent packages manually to control what happens (`apt install …`). But `apt install --fix-broken` Does the job and will get packages only from your configured repository… this will be quite safe.

A third option : compile with the source.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation and additional advices

Answer (score 1):

It's safe to add the `testing` "release" to your sources.list as long as you set a default release.   e.g. add a line to `/etc/apt/apt.conf` with:

```
APT::Default-Release "stable";
```

or create a file with the same line in the directory `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/`

`apt` (and similar programs like `apt-get` and `aptitude`) will only install packages from the default release **unless** you explicitly override that and tell it to use another release with `-t` or specify a target release with the package name.  e.g.

```
apt install -t testing package
```

or

```
apt install package/testing
```

Note: that when you specify a target release, apt will do whatever it needs to do to satisfy dependencies.  So, if a package has a versioned dependency on a version of a package (e.g. a library package) that's in testing but not in stable, it will also upgrade that package.   Be careful and use the `-d`, `-u` and `-V` options to see what apt will do before you allow it to perform the install or upgrade.

Comment: Nice! Thanks. (consider not using the abbreviation in cmd options. It's not read-friendly. I know everybody does, but it doesn't make it any better ;-))